# Find derivative of $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt x}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, derivatives

Find derivative of $\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt x}$ by using the definition of derivative not by using chain rule.
I am stuck with the algebra part.

Comment: Please typeset with LaTex, clarify what you are asking and show what were your efforts before getting stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE community @Jenush S. What is your attempt? What did you try??

Comment: I can't find its derivative

Comment: Do you know the definition of the derivative?

Comment: lim (f(x+h)-f(x))/h

Comment: Yes, that seems correct formula. So your task is now to calculate the limit (when $h \to 0$) given in definition...

Comment: Yes I want to calculate the answer using that formula but I am stuck with the algebra part

Comment: **Hint**: $f(x+h)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+h}}$

Comment: How will I eliminate the h in denominator

Comment: To @JenushS: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x+h}}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt x}}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{1+\sqrt{x}-1-\sqrt{x+h}}{h(1+\sqrt{x+h})(1+\sqrt{x})}$

or

$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h}}{h(1+\sqrt{x+h})(1+\sqrt{x})}$.

Now we will proceed with rationalization, i.e.

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h}}{h(1+\sqrt{x+h})(1+\sqrt{x})}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h}}=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{x-x-h}{h(1+\sqrt{x+h})(1+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})}$$

Hence, we have:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{-h}{h(1+\sqrt{x+h})(1+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})}$$

or

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{-1}{(1+\sqrt{x+h})(1+\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})}=\boxed{\dfrac{-1}{2\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x})^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering

Comment: You're welcome @JenushS and hope you learned something new here at MSE community!

Answer (score -1):

Use the quotient rule of derivative. That is d/dx (f(x)/g(x)). The formula is {g(x)*f'(x)-f(x)g'(x)}/{g(x)}². Now try to solve the question.

Comment: I want the answer using limit

Comment: To @DEB SANKAR ROY: using the definition of the derivative is mandatory in a given problem.

Comment: Ok@AntonVrdoljak. But I have already mentioned the formula of quotient rule of derivative.